# Java + Jackson serialization & deserialization for interface, implemented by enum's

Tags: java, rest, enums, jackson, fasterxml

I am facing issue on deserializing pojo having field as interface which is implemented by multiple enum's

```
public interface interfaceEnum {
}

public enum a implements interfaceEnum {
  A, B, C
}

public enum b implements interfaceEnum {
  D, E, F
}

public class pojo {
 public Integer id;

 public interfaceEnum enum;

 public Integer getId(){
   return id;
 }
 public void setId(Integer id) {
  this.id = id;
 }
 public intefaceEnum getInterfaceEnum() {
   return interfaceEnum;
 }
 public void setIntefaceEnum(intefaceEnum enum){
  this.interfaceEnum = enum;
 }
}
```

> I had also tried to implement custom deserializer by using
>   @JsonDeserialize of fasterxml.jackson on interfaceEnum but i am facing issue is  Content
>   type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported

I need to pass json to pojo from UI side or using rest client, so i need to do both serializing and deserializing the interfaceEnum in pojo.

Thanks in advance for the help. :)

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Comment: Do you facing a compilation error or the runtime ser/deser is not working as expected?

Comment: First, it is really bad practice to name classes or interfaces with a non-capital letter. You should rename the interface to `InterfaceEnum` (instead of `interfaceEnum`).

Comment: i am facing "Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported" if i put @jsondeserialize in pojo on interfaceEnum field. and what should i change so it should set the instance of a or b in interface enum.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel i am facing runtime error ser/deser i am using rest client or passing json from UI. i know how to do on java side if we want to make object for pojo and set interfaceEnum.

Comment: @shmosel Please help me with the solution. I hope the query i have is clear to you.

Comment: @JonyD Please help me with the solution. I hope the query i have is clear to you.